# Setting-up Lua in Cocos Code IDE

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I am starting a new Lua project so I downloaded Cocos2d-x and Cocos Code IDE. How to configure the IDE so that it uses cocos2d-x? See the picture below:

[image]

Whenever I point that to cocos2d-x folder, an error pops-out:

[image]

I am just a beginner, and I chose cocos2d over Corona because it's open-source and free.

Comment: Make sure your cocos2d-x is complete and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using (at least) cocos2d-x version 3.2. I had the same problem when I tried first with version 2.2.5 but, as you will read [on the wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Cocos_Code_IDE) under the heading *Basic Requirements*, you must use 3.2 Final.

In a related vein, though not the cause of your problem, as a Windows user you need to have Python 2.7.x installed.